# HTML - Failed to load the given URL of the image

Tags: html

I am not getting the image displayed in my browser. I have tried my best to no success. Please help.

Here's my directory structure:->

```
MyProject/
    images/
        ->Logo.png
        ->background.png
    js/
    styles/
        ->style.css
    index.php
```

I am calling the image like this:->

```
<section id="pageContent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" width="100" height="100">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I am using LAMP as my server and the directory structure is located in `/var/www/html/MyProject`

I tried in FireFox using Firebug and came across this error:->

`Failed to load the given URL`

And if I directly write the path as `localhost/MyProject/images/Logo.png` in the browser, I get the `You don't have permission to access /MyProject/images/Logo.png on this server.` Error.

Where I am going wrong, kindly point out the mistake.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit machine.

Comment: chmod is probably set incorrectly or a mime type is missing

Comment: kindly help me out then please..

Comment: You can google for either and apply the knowledge. CHMOD is the permissions on the files. Whatever you used to upload to the server will have a way to set the CHMOD.